# How to deploy rabbitmq with flask and docker?

Tags: python, docker, flask, rabbitmq, microservices

I am doing an application with flask for the back part and angular for the front part, with a microservices architecture. 
For the deploy, I am using docker, and now, the problem, is to communicate between services. I have read that the best option es rabbit-mqtt but I have not found any tutorial.

I have little time because it is for finish my degree, so I need a tutorial that allow me to create the comunication between services quickly.

The flask is restless and I use the manager to create API-CRUD.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I did it:

1. Flask server

```
from flask import Flask
import pika
import uuid
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
queue = {}


class FibonacciRpcClient(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host='rabbit'))

        self.channel = self.connection.channel()

        result = self.channel.queue_declare('', exclusive=True)
        self.callback_queue = result.method.queue

        self.channel.basic_consume(
            queue=self.callback_queue,
            on_message_callback=self.on_response,
            auto_ack=True)

    def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        if self.corr_id == props.correlation_id:
            self.response = body

    def call(self, n):
        self.response = None
        self.corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        queue[self.corr_id] = None
        self.channel.basic_publish(
            exchange='',
            routing_key='rpc_queue',
            properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                reply_to=self.callback_queue,
                correlation_id=self.corr_id,
            ),
            body=str(n))
        while self.response is None:
            self.connection.process_data_events()
        queue[self.corr_id] = self.response
        print(self.response)
        return int(self.response)


@app.route("/calculate/<payload>")
def calculate(payload):
    n = int(payload)
    fibonacci_rpc = FibonacciRpcClient()
    threading.Thread(target=fibonacci_rpc.call, args=(n,)).start()
    return "sent " + payload


@app.route("/results")
def send_results():
    return str(queue.items())
```

2. Worker

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='rpc_queue')


def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)


def on_request(ch, method, props, body):
    n = int(body)
    print(" [.] fib(%s)" % n)
    response = fib(n)
    print(" [.] calculated (%s)" % response)

    ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                     routing_key=props.reply_to,
                     properties=pika.BasicProperties(correlation_id=props.correlation_id),
                     body=str(response))
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)


channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(queue='rpc_queue', on_message_callback=on_request)

print(" [x] Awaiting RPC requests")
channel.start_consuming()
```

The above 2 are based on RabbitMQ tutorial on RPC.

3. Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
RUN mkdir code
ADD flask_server.py requirements.txt /code/
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV FLASK_APP flask_server.py
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["flask", "run", "-h", "0.0.0.0"]
```

4. Docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        links: rabbit
        volumes:
            - .:/code
    rabbit:
        hostname: rabbit
        image: rabbitmq:latest
        ports:
            - "5672:5672"
```

Run docker-compose up, and Flask server should start commiunicating with RabbitMQ server.

Comment: Is there a reason to always create a new connection in the endpoint request? Wouldn't it be better to start the connection with flask instead, or am I missing something?

Comment: Quick one @Akalanka Weerasooriya, I'm building a similar architecture and I'm a little bit confused, do you care to explain how this structure will work in Flask. Where will the worker and flask_server be running in order to receive and respond to requests?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to write the RabbitMQ server, the worker and the Dockerfile.
The first answer shows good examples of them.

I'll just emphasize that **the RabbitMQ server might not be ready when the worker** (the *web* service in your case) will **try to reach it**. 
For that **I'll suggest writing the `docker-compose.yml` file like this**:

```
version: "3"

services:

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - .:/code

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    expose:
      - 5672
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "5672" ]
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
```

**So, what I did here?**

1) I've added the [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) and the [restart](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy) properties in the *web* service and the [healthcheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) property in the *rabbit* service. 
Now the *web* service will restart itself until the *rabbit* service becomes healthy.

2) In the *rabbit* service I used the `expose` property instead of `ports` because in your case the 5672 port need to be shared between the containers and doesn't need to be exposed to the host.

From the [Expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose) docs:

> Expose ports without publishing them to the host machine - they’ll
>   only be accessible to linked services. Only the internal port can be
>   specified.

3) I removed the `links` property because (taken from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)):

> Links are not required to enable services to communicate - by default,
>   any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/ZxVpsClqjdw
this videos explains everything with code

and has a docker-compose as

```
version: '3'

services:  

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    hostname: redis

  rabbit:
    hostname: rabbit
    image: rabbitmq:latest
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=mypass

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: web
    command: ./scripts/run_web.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app 
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - rabbit
      - redis

  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ./scripts/run_celery.sh
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - rabbit
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
```

and to make the connection use

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://admin:mypass@rabbit//'
CELERY = Celery('tasks',backend=REDIS_URL,broker=BROKER_URL)
```

for further explanation https://medium.com/swlh/dockerized-flask-celery-rabbitmq-redis-application-f317825a03b